# Display pop up ( alert ) when submit

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a situation where I need to submit the form and display an alert message after the  action completes. I am sending request from xyz.jsp and after submit, xyz.jsp will be displayed back in the browser with modified data.

My code in servlet looks as below.

```
public void doPost(......)
{
   //process input value.

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  
    response.setContentType("text/html");  
    out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");  
    out.println("alert('"+message+"');");  
    out.println("</script>"); 
    RequestDispatcher rd = sc.getRequestDispatcher(/xyz.jsp);
    rd.forward(request, response);
}
```

But when I submit, the pop up will not appear, but xyz.jsp will be loaded in the browser.

Could anyone please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: Try `out.println("alert(\'message\');");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is sent to another file while you are forwarding to a jsp. By doing this, the reference of what you are trying to alert is lost. Use `include()` instead of `forward()`. That should solve your problem.

Comment: Hi Aashray, its working if I use include() instead of forward(). Thanks!